# custom check box and label overlapping in css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i am new to css and html, i am trying to create custom checkbox with list of options, i used one of the option from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox to create checkbox, but after using div of span and label are overlapping and not aligned.

[image]

i am aware i can fix this with proper margin alignment on label, but i am afraid this might not be elegant solution as it can affect the alignment with different screen resolution, even if i put the label inside the div and apply properties to div  the span and label keep on overlapping, is there any better way to do it and need to understand why the span and label keep on overlapping?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: code is same as  in the link i posted(copy paste), answered posted below is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are also using the `bootstrap` framework, some class names may be confused. For example, like `.container`

Comment: yes indeed replaced container class name with cont and it worked !!